# Connect to server via FTP with Notepad++

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ (6.5.3 version) to edit my files. I want to connect to my server with Notepad++. I using this method:

> Open Notepad++ -> Plugins -> NppFTP -> Show NppFTP window

In the NppFTP window:

```
 Click settings button -> profile setting -> add name to site
               -> add host name
               -> username
               -> pwd
         click close.
```

Now i tried to connect my server in notepad++, but it give a following message

```
[NppFTP] Everything initialized
-> TYPE I
Connecting
-> Quit
Unable to connect
Disconnected
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: are you using a proxy server?

Comment: yes my system is in proxy.

Comment: Notepad++ is missing a global proxy interface. In the help menu there is a menu item *Set Updater Proxy*, which is targeting the update module. Other plugins have to manage proxy individually. I can use FTP via other clients in my corporate environment but here NppFTP has no such options and i end up getting the same messages mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

For me the plugin works only with plain **FTP** connection. Once I switch to **FTPS** or **FTPES**, the problem emerges. After diagnosing I've discovered that **FTPS** and **FTPES** modes cause plugin to send invalid commands to the server. I have filled a [ticket at NPP FTP website](https://sourceforge.net/p/nppftp/bugs/63/). Please follow it to obtain the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
Under `Profile Settings`, in `Connection Type`, I changed it to `SFTP` from `FTP` and it worked! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because of your ISP blocking port 21 when using FTPES. You can either use some VPN client or proxy server for bypassing this issue. Your connection will definitely work. I have already tested and resolved this issue for me.