# Connect to server via FTP with Notepad++?

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I'm trying to log into my FTP account through Notepad++ but I cant get it to connect for the life of me.  I know the password and hostname are correct because it works fine in filezilla.

I get the following info in the output:

```
-> TYPE I  
Connecting
-> Quit  
Unable to connect
Disconnected
```

I'm using

NPPv6.5.4

NppFTPv0.24.1

Incase it matters, the hostname is through awardspace.net `dck.dx.am` connection mode is passive, transfer mode is binary, everything else is default...

Thanks in advance for the help,
Dave

Comment: Maybe start is as admin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same results. The plugin worked before, it looks it is now broken. Starting as admin doesn't help, too. Maybe you can downgrade it to some older version and retry. If someone has time, he can [fill a support request directly at NPP FTP homepage](http://sourceforge.net/p/nppftp/support-requests/). As problems with this plugin are frequent, I switched to a [different solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241791/notepad-ftp-keep-disconnecting-and-freeze-after-5-minute-of-inactivity/22874778#22874778) - see the second paragraph of that post.

**EDIT:** I've made some plugin diagnostics, please [follow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694849/connect-to-server-via-ftp-with-notepad/22887243#22887243).

Answer (score 0):

Connecting
-> Quit 
Unable to connect
No more explanation of the error.
The reason was, remote machine doesn’t allow FTP connections at all! 
So Use sftp (select from connetion type)
this will work