# Notepad++ FTP Keep disconnecting and freeze after 5 minute of inactivity

Tags: ftp, notepad++, freeze

**Notepad++ FTP Keep disconnecting and freeze after 5 minute of inactivity**

> Did anyone get this problem too? 
>   If yes did anyone succeed to fix it?
>   It is very frustrating while programming because after 5 minutes of
>   scripting  when I come to save the file with the FTP plugin of
>   notepad++ it freeze in the background and I must wait 50 seconds, plus
>   I need to re-save right after because it didn't the time it frozen.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's really really annoying.  Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are encountering [a known defect](http://sourceforge.net/p/nppftp/bugs/53/).

Honestly, I have switched away from N++ FTP plugin because of its numerous issues. For the sake of this question I gave it a try and recently it does not seem to work at all. I have found at least 2 new questions [asking for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235364/connect-to-server-via-ftp-with-notepad) with the problem. Currently I'm with shareware Total Commander 8.50. After I connect to FTP and start editing files (each using <kbd>F4</kbd>) it keeps an eye on them and after saving a file it reuploads it back instantly. (Note: Version 8.50 is required for this functionality.)